# shoes url not working in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ruby, ubuntu, shoes

i have been using Shoes in windows from couple of months and it was working awesome, but now i am having Ubuntu set up on my machine and i am trying to run shoes in it but it seems like URL is not working .... i.e nothing happens when i click on it.
Have anybody observed this problem.
Any help on this?
thanks
Pradyumna

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're running shoes? (no pun intended). Can you provide a URL?

Comment: Please provide a testable code fragment

Comment: actually i was talking about Shoes.url ... i even tried running the sample program of BookList but the URL is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, this would seem to to be the relevant bit:

[shoes/native/gtk.c](http://github.com/shoes/shoes/blob/master/shoes/native/gtk.c#L611-L617)

```
shoes_browser_open(char *url)
{
    VALUE browser = rb_str_new2("/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser '");
    rb_str_cat2(browser, url);
    rb_str_cat2(browser, "' 2>/dev/null &");
    shoes_sys(RSTRING_PTR(browser), 1);
}
```

Not overly familiar with Ubuntu, but perhaps in your installation `/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser` isn't pointing to the right place? Either that, or Shoes shouldn't be using this path?

Comment: Sorry, I've just read your comment under your question. I thought your problem was with something like `para link("Link", :click => "http://www.url.com")` not opening  a web browser. But it is actually with internal links, such as the class-book.rb sample.

Answer (score 0):

Sad to say that Shoes.url indeed seems broken on Linux, at least it was on Linux Mint (main edition, Ubuntu based) as well some time ago.

However I just tried it, now running Linux Mint Debian Edition, with the current shoes head and it worked beautifully. So either it's an Ubuntu specific problem or its fixed on the current Head. You could try to [check out the current head](https://github.com/shoes/shoes)